# Foreign object removed after it was added to another in Entity Framework 6.1

Tags: entity-framework

This sounds strange but in fact is simple.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Platillo
{
    [Key] 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // ..Several properties
    public virtual ICollection<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
}

public class Cat
{
    [Key] 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then when I update a `Platillo` object I do the following:

```
public JsonResult Edit(Platillo p)
{
    Platillo pAux = Bd.Platillos.Include("Cats")
                      .Single<Platillo>(x => x.ID == p.ID);

    pAux.Name = p.Name;
    // Setting several properties
    pAux.Categorias.Clear();

    foreach (Cat c in p.Cats)
    {
        Categoria cc = Bd.Cats.Single<Cat>(ca => ca.ID == c.ID);
        pAux.Cats.Add(cc);
    }

    Bd.SaveChanges();

    return Json(pAux.ID);
}
```

Let's say there are these objects in the DB:

```
Cat_1

Platillo1
Platillo2
```

The problem is that, if the object Cat1 is assigned to Platillo1 and then it is assigned to Platillo2, it is going to be erased from Platillo1

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Cat`-`Platillo` relationship is *-1 or many-to-one. A `Cat` can have only one `Platillo` while `Platillo` can have many `Cat`s.

There is a foreign key in `Cat` table which is rewritten in case you assign it to Platillo2.

Consider using many-to-many relationship between `Cat` and `Platillo`. There will be additional table in your db storing both `Cat` and `Platillo` ids. You will not have a corresponding model class for this table. EF will use it implicitly.

Check out [this link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) for configuring many-to-many relationship in EF.

If you are using code-first approach try changing your model class to this

```
public class Cat
{
    [Key] 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Platillo> Platillos { get; set; }
}
```

> Is there any other way? I would rather not to add the property.

Yes, there is a way to do it with fluent API. Put this code to `OnModelCreating` method of your context class.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Platillo>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Cats)
    .WithMany() // <- no parameter here because there is no navigation property
```

Comment: As far as I know I can do that adding the following property in Cat class: public virtual ICollection<Platillo> Plats { get; set; }. Is there any other way? I would rather not to add the property.

Comment: Is there any other way? I would rather not to add the property.

Comment: Updated the answer. Use fluent API.